# Are there any benefits to an Option type in a dynamically-typed language?

Tags: optionals, nullability, dynamic-typing

Going off of [this question](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/360/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-an-option-type-in-comparison-to-nullable-types/367#367) about the difference between nullable types and optional types, I notice that no mainstream dynamically typed language has ever gone for an explicitly-boxed `Option` type. Python, Ruby, and Javascript all have null values, called (respectively) `None`, `nil`, and `null`.

Obviously, we could define such a type with something like

```
class Option:
  def __init__(self, is_empty, value):
    self.is_empty = is_empty
    self.value = value
  def map(self, f):
    if self.is_empty:
      return Option(True, None)
    else:
      return Option(False, f(self.value))
  # ... and other helper functions ...
```

What would be the benefits of adding something like this to the standard library in a language where types are not checked at compile time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the pros and cons of an Option type in comparison to nullable types?](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/360/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-an-option-type-in-comparison-to-nullable-types)

Comment: @ArthurAraruna That talks about Option types and nullable types (at compile time) in statically typed languages. This question is specifically about dynamically typed languages.

Answer (score 8):

### Nesting

In a language with `Option`s, you can have a function that takes a list of values and returns a new list with those same values wrapped in `Some`s. In a language without `Option`s, you couldn't do that, as there'd be no way to distinguish between `Some(None)` and `None`.

Answer (score 8):

Functional-style handling comes to mind. Even in your example, you have introduced a `map` method. This kind of API is very convenient for chained operations on `Option`s, and cannot be easily provided for a dynamic `None` (unless you make such methods common to all objects)